# Problems with a regression model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have issues with my homework. I have a data set of users and their ratings for movies. I created a pandas dataframe, that looks like this:
[image: Here is an image of a portion of the dataframe]

I split the dataframe into learning subset (75%) and test subset. I created the models (Lasso, LinearRegression, ridge..). Now my job is to create my own user, and rate some movies. Then test the models on my user, to see if the predictions are somewhat right. However, I have no idea how to test it on just my user. I added my user to the dataframe. From there further im a bit lost.

```
df["672"] = uporabnik
train=df.sample(frac=0.75,random_state=200)
test=df.drop(train.index)

#users.append("672")
mse = []
for i in users:
    x = np.array(train.drop(columns=["movieId", "title", i]), dtype='float')
    y = np.array(train.filter([i]), dtype='float')

    x_test = np.array(test.drop(columns=["movieId", "title", i]), dtype='float')
    y_test = np.array(test.filter([i]), dtype='float')

    model = Lasso(alpha=0.1)
    model.fit(x,y)
    hx = model.predict(x_test)
    mse.append(mean_squared_error(hx,y_test))
    MSE = mean_squared_error(hx,y_test)
    if(MSE > 0 and MSE < 1):
        if(i == '672'):
            print(hx)
```

this is the code I have for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not see any issues on your code, you are checking the `MSE` when the user is `672` which I believe is the user you created. This is more conceptual but, keep in mind that you are training your model with all users, to predict the scores of your user. Try using other ML models for regression, i.e Ridge, OLS,  and maybe check other scores like r2, there is a bunch of scores for regressions here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

Comment: Is there a way for me to get results for all movies instead of just the ones in test subset? So basically I would use all my cases as the learning subset and only use my user as the test.

Comment: Sure, you can train your model with all records and validate with all records, but this is not correct because your model's loss function was minimized according to the training set, in other words, it is likely to answer correctly most of the times. The idea of a machine learning model is the concept of generalization, if your model can answer correctly cases it hasn't seen, then the model has generalized the knowledge and is able to predict new information.